# Is storing JSON in data attriibute recommended over having seperate data attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

I am storing the following data attribute for select elements for loading the options.

```
<select name="DependsOn_Field" data-load='automatic' data-source='web.module().fields' data-value='name' data-display='label' data-filter='exclude_single' id='DependantField'></select>
```

My questions is what is the best way when need to store many data attributes for a single DOM element? Is it better to have single data attribute having the JSON data or having separate data attributes for each value needed.

Comment: Individual data attributes are probably more maintainable, if you store JSON inside of a data field you will still need to parse the JSON.

Comment: I guess the attributes would be more readable, but the JSON would be a more logical way to store a lot of data. The attributes are also more accessible whereas the JSON needs to be converted to an object to be read and back to a string if changes are made. Ideally you would have JavaScript objects that hold the data and are linked to a node, avoiding this problem altogether.

Comment: If the JSON is not the wanted value itself, I would never use it just to "pack" lots of attributes. It simply is not what it is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question boils down to are the data attributes static? Are they possibly ever going to change? If they are going to change or you may want to edit them, then JSON is definitely better. However if they are static and you are just going to read those attributes, I think the data attribute is fine, this is exactly what the data attribute is for. I know it looks cumbersome because you have a bunch of attributes but I think it's fine.

**EDIT** by change or edit, I mean edit them dynamically in the clients browser.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

That's entirely dependant on how they are being used.

If your values are simple strings and you are accessing them from JavaScript, then it likely makes sense to keep them in `data-` attributes.

If your values are complex JSON objects, then it may make more sense to store the complete JSON value in a `data-` attribute, and define a helper that will read it (assuming for simplicity that jQuery is available):

```
function getElemData(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var elemData = $elem.data("_jsonData");
    if (!elemData) {
        elemData = JSON.parse($elem.attr("data-json-data"));
        $elem.data("_jsonData", elemData);
    }
    return elemData;
}
```

And finally, if the data are just being passed around (ex, written by the server, then read and sent directly on somewhere else), it most likely makes sense to keep the entire blob in a single `data-` attribut.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One correction is jQuery checks the value in data attribute and parses it if it starts with {.

Comment: Ug, right — I forgot about the abhorrent behaviour of `$.data`. Ug. Yes — because of that parsing magic, using `$.data` to access `data-` attributes should absolutely never be used, hence the need for the helper function. In this case, the attribute or data name should be changed (which I've done).